# Cordova camera plugin does not use both Camera and Photo library to upload

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to use both camera and photo library on one button click using cordova camera plugin. We can use sourceType to specify the same but it only uses one at a time (Camera or Library).

If it is not possible to do via cordova camera plugin then please let me know any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First - Do you need this for iOS or Android?

Second - On android devices you can't do it! For this you need to add additional button. On iOS you have popup-dialog to choose between different sources (like Library or camera App).